# Forcing embedded plotly plot to full screen

Tags: html, r, plotly

I embedded a plotly plot in my html as an iframe using the code below
`<iframe width="100%" height="500" src="fig3_small.html" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

The plot was generated in R and exported as html. However, once embedded in the html, the plot its constrained by the dimensions of the iframe, and I was wondering if there is a trick to forcing the plot to open full screen either as a pop-up or in a new tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to embed your plotly graph as an `<iframe>` in order to be able to open it in a new tab. Simply pass it as a hyperlink in your website as demonstrated in the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Plotly Graph</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br>
    <div><a href = "fig3_small.html" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Plotly Graph</strong></h1></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When you click the **Plotly Graph** button, it will display your plot as a full screen in another window tab.

I hope this helps!